# New Wordpress blog template to display only one category

Tags: wordpress, blogs, categories

I understand that I can copy my theme's default blog template and change the code to make it display only posts from one category in the theme's style. I tried tinkering with it, but to no result yet. This is the code in the theme:

```
$posts = new WP_Query( array('post_type'=>'post', 'paged'=>$paged) );
            if( $posts->have_posts() ):
                echo '<div class="list-posts">';
                while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post();
                    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); 
                endwhile;
                echo '</div>';

                wp_reset_postdata();
            else:
                echo '<div class="alert alert-error">'.esc_html__('Sorry. There are no posts to display', 'gon').'</div>';
            endif;
```

I tried changing the values on `while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post();`  but to no success.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try altering the first line -- that's where the criteria for selecting posts are defined.

You could do something like this:

`$posts = new WP_Query( array('post_type'=>'post', 'paged'=>$paged, 'category_name' => 'my-category') ); // use category slug`

or, alternatively, using the numerical category ID:

`$posts = new WP_Query( array('post_type'=>'post', 'paged'=>$paged, 'cat' => 3) ); // use category id`

Comment: Thank you, good Sir. Worked like a charm :) Got this problem solved after hours searching the web!